# demystify super in python?

Tags: python, super

I was trying to understand how super works in python and tried the following example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "in A's init"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "in B's init"

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C,self).__init__()
        print "In C"

if __name__=="__main__":
    c=C()
```

fairly simple.. And I tried the following super calls(displayed with the results here):

```
>>> super(B,c).__init__()
>>> super(B,c).__init__()
>>> super(A,c).__init__()
    in B's init
>>> super(A,c).__init__()
    in B's init
>>> super(A,c).__init__()
    in B's init
>>> super(B,c).__init__()
>>> super(C,c).__init__()
    in A's init
```

I do not understand why does `super(A,c).__init__()` print out that its in B's init??

Comment: This is a recurrent question. The answer could be reach at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods

Comment: This is a great post about super: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: Hernan's link is useful. As a counterpoint, it's also useful to know about some of the problems with `super`: https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: Nothing in the answers to that question goes into any detail on multiple inheritance. The closest they get is linking to other information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python's *super()* should have been been called "next-in-mro" because it doesn't necessarily call upwards to a parent; rather, it can call a sibling instead.

It is easy to inspect the method resolution order of your class structure:

```
 >>> C.__mro__
 (<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

You can see that *B* is the next class after *A*.

The reason for this design is that it lets the chain of super calls visit every class in the chain no more than once.   That supports a style of programming called "cooperative multiple inheritance" which is sometimes very useful.

Here are some references including links to Dylan's next-method that served as a model for Python's super():

- http://opendylan.org/books/drm/Method_Dispatch#HEADING-50-32
- http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/
- http://opendylan.org/proposals/dep-0003.html
- http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127