# Python multiple inheritance is not showing class variables or method of second inherited base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Hello awesome community,
I was learning the OOPS concepts with python as a part of my curriculum. I am having a problem with multiple inheritance in python. The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base1var = "this is base1"


class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base2var = "this is base2"

class MainClass(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MainClass()
    print a.base1var
    print a.base2var
```

and when running, I am getting the following error

```
print a.base2var
AttributeError: 'MainClass' object has no attribute 'base2var'
```

If I swap the order of classes inherited, the variable name in the error changes accordingly.

Am I using `super()` wrong when I want to call the constructors of the two inherited classes?

How can I correctly inherit from multiple base classes and use the variables and methods in the main class without this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ if you want to know how to use `super` *properly*.

Comment: Thank you @chepner. That's valuable.

Comment: FWIW, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565192/4014959) by core dev Raymond Hettinger has some good links about `super`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `super` call to Base1 so that Base2's `__init__` will get called after Base1's. You can also add a `super` call to Base2. It's not necessary, but it won't hurt.

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base1, self).__init__()
        self.base1var = "this is base1"

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(Base2, self).__init__()
        self.base2var = "this is base2"

class MainClass(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MainClass()
    print a.base1var
    print a.base2var
```

**output**

```
this is base1
this is base2
```

BTW, you really should be using Python 3. `super` is much nicer in modern Python. :)

Comment: Arguably, `super` is easier to understand in Python 2; since you can't dispense with the arguments, you are forced (at least a little) to contemplate *why* the particular arguments are necessary. Python 3 could lead one to wonder why `super` is a callable at all, rather than just a keyword referring to the current class. (It's undeniably more *convenient* in Python 3 for the vast majority of use cases, though.)

Comment: @chepner I guess so. `super` in Python 3 may be a little _too_ magical. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `super()`, you must use it *consistently* to ensure all classes' methods are called. Your `Base1` and `Base2` classes should also call `super(...).__init__()` in their `__init__()` methods. This will ensure that all classes in the method resolution order are eventually called.

This does get a little tricky when not all `__init__()` methods have an empty argument list. At some point, `super()` will have you calling `object.__init__()`, and that never takes any arguments. The trouble is, you might not know which classes this might happen in ahead of time. You can remedy this by creating an `object` subclass that takes any number of arguments in `__init__()`, and deriving from that. That class needn't call `object.__init__()` because that method doesn't actually do anything (or, if you're paranoid that that might change, you can call `object.__init__()` without using `super()`).

In general, `super()` requires extra care in argument handling because you might not know which class will be next in the method resolution order, since users of your code might make new classes using your base classes in combinations you haven't anticipated. So you'll need to do some work to make sure the method signatures in all your classes are compatible.

For more information, see Raymond Hettinger's seminal [Python's Super() Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 2):

Basically what is happening is that Python is looking through the parent classes (and their parents, etc. See the link at the end of this paragraph) for some method `__init__`.  It reads the classes left to right so it sees `Base1` first.  Since `Base1.__init__` exists, that method is called. Read a more detailed explanation at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277407/6779307).

I believe the only way to call all of the appropriate methods is to do so manually

```
class MainClass(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        Base1.__init__(self)
        Base2.__init__(self)
```

then

```
a = MainClass()
print(a.base1var)
print(a.base2var)
```

prints

```
this is base1
this is base2
```

Comment: Not the parent classes; it is picking the next method in the MRO, which may include classes not known statically to `MainClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Base1 `__init__` overrides Base2 `__init__.py` so `base2var` is never created.

You should use `super`, see [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

It is not mistake to use the super but not for that goal.Explained [super](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#super)
I have changed your code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base1var = "this is base1"


class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base2var = "this is base2"

class MainClass(Base2, Base1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MainClass()
    print (a.base2var)
```

Than you have

```
this is base2
```

Comment: `super` doesn't even necessarily pick a parent; it uses the *next* method in the MRO, which may not even be known statically.

Comment: @chepner I agree will try to reformulate.